# How to add a default directory to QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName in python

Tags: python, pyqt

hello I am tring to to add a default directory to my save file dialog.

how can I add it to  this code:

```
self._saveFilePath = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,"saveFlle","Result.txt",filter ="txt (*.txt *.)")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
self._saveFilePath = QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,"saveFlle","Result.txt",filter ="txt (*.txt *.)")
```

Where `"saveFlle"` is a caption and `"Result.txt"` is a default dir.

From doc:

> The file dialog's working directory will be set to dir. If dir
>   includes a file name, the file will be selected.

So you should set path to dir, for example: `"D:/"`